# Object sharing in Swing Framework

Tags: java, swing

I've just started learning Java and have some noob questions. Below there is almost full listing of my program, because now I'd like to hear all the critics I can.

The "problem" I'm trying to solve is how to share an `JLabel` object between `JPanels` so that I can handle the events like `MousePressed`? I managed to handle a MousePressed event from PlotSurface: after I move somehow the cursor on the plane the `JLabel` coords get refreshed. But the code looks ugly to me. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

The goal is to handle events from `ControlsPanel` (X,Y,Z and R can be changed). I'd like to draw a circle on the `PlotSurface` after these four are changed.

```
class PlotSurface extends JPanel {
    private ColoredCircle redCircle = new ColoredCircle();
    private Point start = new Point(0,0);
    private JLabel _label;
    public PlotSurface(JLabel label) 
    {
        _label = label;
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                String pos = redCircle.getX() + "," + redCircle.getY();
                _label.setText(pos);
                moveCircle(e.getX(),e.getY());
            }
        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
               String pos = redCircle.getX() + "," + redCircle.getY();
                _label.setText(pos);
                moveCircle(e.getX(),e.getY());
            }
        });

    }

    private void moveCircle(int x, int y) {

        final int CURR_X = redCircle.getX();
        final int CURR_Y = redCircle.getY();
        final int CURR_W = redCircle.getWidth();
        final int CURR_H = redCircle.getHeight();
        final int OFFSET = 1;

        if ((CURR_X!=x) || (CURR_Y!=y)) {

        // The circle is moving, repaint background over the old square location. 
        repaint(CURR_X,CURR_Y,CURR_W+OFFSET,CURR_H+OFFSET);

        // Update coordinates.
        redCircle.setX(x);
        redCircle.setY(y);

        // Repaint the circle at the new location.
        repaint(redCircle.getX(), redCircle.getY(), 
        redCircle.getWidth()+OFFSET, 
        redCircle.getHeight()+OFFSET);
        }

    }

 @Override 
  public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
       return new Dimension(150,150);
   } 

 @Override 
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponent(g);       
       String pos = redCircle.getX() + "," + redCircle.getY();
       Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
       g2.drawString(pos,10,10); 
       g2.drawLine(0,getHeight()/2,getWidth(),getHeight()/2);
       g2.drawLine(getWidth()/2,0,getWidth()/2,getHeight());
       g2.fillOval(100,100,50,50);
       redCircle.paintCircle(g2);
  }     

}

class ColoredCircle{ //
 it know how to draw itself   }

class ControlsHeader extends JPanel 
{
    public ControlsHeader() {
        super();          
        JLabel lblR = new JLabel();
        lblR.setText("R: ");
        //...
        JSpinner x = new JSpinner(model);
        //...
        JComboBox y = new JComboBox();
        //..
        ButtonGroup z = new ButtonGroup();

         }
  }

class ControlsFooter extends JPanel 
{
    public ControlsFooter()
    {
        super();
        //a couple of elements
    }
}


class ControlsFrame extends JFrame 
{
    public ControlsFrame(String title) 
    {
        super(title);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));

        JLabel coords = new JLabel();
        coords.setText("COORDS");
        coords.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        JPanel footer = new ControlsFooter();
        footer.add(coords); 

        add(new PlotSurface(coords), BorderLayout.CENTER);        
        add(new ControlsHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(footer, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}
public class Lab4UI {

    private static void startGUI() {  
        JFrame frame = new ControlsFrame("Lab 4. №36");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {  
               startGUI(); 
        }});
}

}
```

Comment: Focus on spheres of responsibility. You don't want to expose your label to other parts of your program who shouldn't be able to update it (exposing the label could allow a part of your program the ability to remove it - trust no one ;)). Instead, supply methods that allow other parts of your program to register interest. If you need to change the value, consider using a setters and getters

Comment: Any time you hear yourself saying "the code looks ugly to me" it is a sign that you need to post the question on codereview.stackexchange.com, not here.

Comment: @MadProgrammer What mechanisms am I to use in this particular situation? I'm well aware of getters/setters/..  The code had already been to long to publish. That's why they're missed here :)

Comment: @enter_the_bot You want to focus on any solution that prevents you from having to pass a reverence of the label to some other object.  Maybe using an observe pattern for example.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've always used an observer pattern when I had to send  messages from one sender to several listeners. Here I need the opposite (several senders, i.e. JComboBoxes, JSpinner etc and MouseEvents) that are needed to be handled in the similar way: put a circle on the PlotSurface and refresh the JLabel on the footer. Is an observer pattern the best choice here?

Comment: I would think so.  But what I would do is provide some kind of interface that allowed each of these components to perform the required actions without exposing unnecessary parts of your application.

Answer (score 1):

Labels are individuals, might have other texts, icons, positions, sizes. You could make your label class extending JLabel. But best seems to keep a separate class that may add/provide a MouseAdapter to/for a JLabel.

Sharing a JLabel is not feasible, as a realised component has a fixed parent container.

I cannot judge the overall context, but for myself I would first design an abstract system: plot surfaces, controlled by the mouse, maybe some common managing class sharing logic.

Maybe make two as independent as possible JPanel components, and then look what can be shared.

---

No need for coords to be given externally, as a JLabel cannot be shared.

```
public class PlotSurface extends JPanel {
    private ColoredCircle redCircle = new ColoredCircle();
    private Point start = new Point(0,0);
    private JLabel coords = new JLabel();
    private final MouseAdapter mouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            String pos = redCircle.getX() + "," + redCircle.getY();
            coords.setText(pos);
            moveCircle(e.getX(),e.getY()); // Or one param: e.getPoint().
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            String pos = redCircle.getX() + "," + redCircle.getY();
            coords.setText(pos);
            moveCircle(e.getX(),e.getY());
        }
    };

    public PlotSurface() 
    {
        coords.setText("COORDS");
        coords.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);
        addMouseMotionListener(mouseAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: adding/providing a Mouseadapter is what I'm looking for. I'm not sure what the implementation must be like :( Could you be a little more  elaborate on the design of this abstract system. It'd be a great help!

Comment: I have added actual code. mouseDragged and mousePressed could even call one method of PlotSurface here.

Comment: thanks! But I don't see a way to share events with other classes. what if I wanted to change the coordinated by explicitly typing them in my ControlsHeader's JSpinner? After the calue of the spinner has changed, I'd like JLabel in the header to be refreshed. What is a clean way out? I don't mind throw out the whole code. I feel like I'm missing some important detail.

Comment: Look at how the [MVC](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_Controller) (**Model View Controller**) framework works. The linked article gives a better guideline than I could do here. Sorry, hope MVC is what you are seeking for.